# emacs buffer menu does not show all buffers

Tags: emacs

When I pull down the emacs buffer menu, if I have a lot of buffers, I see only a subset of them listed. So, I then have to do List All Buffers. Is there a way to configure the Buffer Menu so that it will show all buffers? Xemacs always did that, but we no longer are able to use that.

Comment: Although most people don't care about the hidden buffers that begin with a space, here is a modification to see those if you are ever so inclined:  http://superuser.com/questions/645873/menu-buffers-not-listing/645888#645888

Answer (score 1):

Adjust `buffers-menu-max-size`:

```
(setq buffers-menu-max-size nil)
```

From the `C-h v buffers-menu-max-size` on my version of Emacs 24.3:

> Maximum number of entries which may appear on the Buffers menu.
>
> If this is 10, then only the ten most-recently-selected buffers are shown.
>
> If this is nil, then all buffers are shown.
> A large number or nil slows down menu responsiveness.